# Get the day number for tomorrow PHP

Tags: php, date

To get the numerical representation of the 7 day week you do this :

```
echo date('N'); // 2 (Tuesday)
```

Is there a built in function to get tomorrow's numerical day?

I know how I could do it programatically, but I was wondering if there was a function to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), which can take a string expressing a relative date e.g.

```
echo date('N', strtotime('tomorrow'));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to `+1 day`:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('N');
```

Or alternatively just set the modification in `DateTime()` directly:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('N');
```

Other relative date statements are available as well, such as `tomorrow`. These are detailed on the [Supported Date and Time Formats: Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) manual page.

Comment: Noted and fixed :)

Comment: No need for the `->modify()` can use `new \DateTime('tomorrow')` or `new \DateTime('+1 day')`  https://3v4l.org/bKJUv or even `date_create('tomorrow')->format('N')`

Comment: Thanks for the alternative answer but I'm curious why this has more upvotes than the answer I accepted seeing as this is much longer than the one liner provided by Nick? What are the benefits to doing it this way as opposed to using `strtotime`?